# How to perform a React state update when working with history Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, browser-history

I just wrote a small piece of code, for simplicity, and to stay focused on the problem.
I have a component that has a Dialog, which is part of one commercial process where you can fill some information like a note and you can approve the sale or not.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Modal = ({
  closeModal,
  open
}) => {

  const [note, setNote] = useState('')
  const [approved, setApproved] = ('')
  
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
     setNote('')
     setApproved('')
    
    },[open])
```

This function makes the asynchronous Job, once you filled the info, you click on save button, it closes the modal and then move you to another phase of the commercial process which is done by the history.push

```
const update = () => {
    return updatePromise({ notes, approved }).then(() => {
      closeModal();

      if (approved === 'yes') {
        history.push('/route');
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={closeModal}>
      <Notes value={note} />

      <ActionsButton
        closeModal={closeModal}
        disabled={!approved.length > 0}
        save={update}
        buttonName={'save'}
      />
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Everything is working fine, but when you click on save button, a warning appears to the console saying that "Warning: Can’t perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

After debugging a while, I found that the problem is on the promise when I am pushing into the history the new url on the conditional and I have no idea what else to do.

How can I use this history.push properly in order to clear the side effects on the state update?

Comment: These documentation will help you to understand the promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Do you mind adding where and how you use the `update` function? You think the promise is the issue, yet you currently don't provide the info where and how you invoke this promise.

Comment: I already updated the code, maybe it is more clear @3limin4t0r

Comment: the problem it is not the promise it self, is the codition to push into history a new url once the modal is closed, but that should be done there, so what could I do on useEffect to avoid the warning? @3limin4t0r

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is on the `useEffect` level, as described in the warning message you recieve.

I believe you use the `useEffect` hook to clear the modal form. If that's true, you don't really need to clear it when it's false. So if you add an `if` statement in the `useEffect` hook, checking if `open` is `true`. It will solve your warning message at least.

```
useEffect(() => {
 //when modal is closed(open === false)
 if(open) { //this will check for truthy values. and the state will not update when open is false
   setNote('')
   setApproved(false)
 }
},[open])
```

Comment: as I mentioned, the problem is on the promise, because onSave action the modal closes and the history.push('path') is still in progress